# If $\gcd(a,1729) \neq 1$, show that $a^{37 }\equiv a \pmod {1729}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm, totient-function

The question is for any integer $a$, show that $a^{37} \equiv a \pmod{1729}$. 
I have already proven using fermat's little theorem that if $a$ and $1729$ are relatively prime, then it is true, but I do not know how to do it if they are not. Please help.

Comment: Is 1729 prime or composite?

Comment: $1729 = 13 * 7 * 19$

Comment: @ShawnSalvatore And do you know a way to exploit that fact? Do you know any theorem that cares at all about the factorisation of the modulus?

Comment: @Arthur Most theorem i know requires relative prime, so that is why I am at a lost. Can you help guide me what am I missing here?

Comment: How did you use Fermat's little theorem, by the way? You can't use Fermat's little on $1729$.

Comment: What I did was use it on $7$,$13$ and $19$, to establish that $a^{37} \equiv a \pmod{7} $ , $13$ , and $19$ respectively, so then this shows that $7$, $13$ and $19$ divides $a^{37} - a$ and since $7, 13$ and $19$ are all relatively prime pairwise, thus $1729$ divides $a^{37} - a$ so $a^37 \equiv a \pmod{1729}$

Comment: @Shawn That's a correct way to proceed, e.g. see the proofs in the linked dupes. You need to do the cases $\,p\mid a\,$ separately, but they are trivial, since $\,p\mid a\Rightarrow\, p\mid a^{37}-a\ \ $

Comment: Thanks @BillDubuque , I see it now.

Comment: i.e. the two cases arise from $\,p\mid a(a^{36}-1)\iff p\mid a\,$ or $\,p\mid a^{36}-1,\,$ by $p$ prime, to be precise.